# SSH Key Generation

Tags: ssh

So I know this is a dumb question, but its just a matter of me not knowing the correct terminology.

When you ssh into Amazon EC2 instances, you provide a key file with `-i` parameter of `ssh` like so:

`ssh -i mykeyfile.pem root@ec2-blah-blop-blam.amazon.com`

How could I generate a key file for an in house server so that I can have scripts ssh into the machine via the generated key file?

Or if key file is not the right word, what is the technical term for `mykeyfile.pem`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use `ssh-keygen` to generate an SSH public and private key.

You keep the private key (the file you supply to `ssh` with `-i`) on your machine, and push the public key out to the servers.

Quoting `man ssh`:

```
 -i identity_file
             Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read.
```

Comment: the private key stays on the server to which I want to have other servers ssh to right? `mykeyfile.pem` is the public key?

Comment: There are two keys, public and private. By default, on Debian / Ubuntu, these files are called `id_rsa.pub` (public) and `id_rsa` (private).

The public key belongs on the server you are ssh'ing TO. The private key is for the server you are ssh'ing FROM.

Comment: Could you provide example syntax so that a key would be created that I could use like the example ssh command I show above? Should I use RSA or DSA?

Comment: It's just `ssh-keygen`. It will ask you where on disk you want to store the file, and what name it will have. Then just push the `.pub` version to the server.

Comment: @thatidiotguy - NO. Users' private keys should **never** leave their workstation. That's why it's called private. The public key goes out on the server.